# Selenium:How can I delay the closing of a browser let's say for 5 sec

Tags: selenium, automation

I have run all my Tests successfully and I have used the driver.close command at the end but I want to delay the closing of a browser for 5 or 10 sec which means once all tests gets executed then browser waits for like 5 sec and then gets close. Is it possible to do this and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just *add a "sleep"* before calling `close()`.

In Python:

```
import time

time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

In Java:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.close();
```

Comment: Worked ! Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Selenium 2.x api (not 3.x), you can do it like so, and you **wont have to** change the test methods signature to throw a InterruptedException :

```
Sleeper.sleepTight(2000);
```

Usually, I start the web browser in the tests `@Before` annotated method and then in the `@After` annotated method I will stick that sleeper and then a driver.close.   Sometimes, just before the sleep, I will navigate the page to a success page and display that just before the browser closes.